# Why did my comment get deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comments, specific-question

I posted a comment on this post: [android nfc setting toggle listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221535/android-nfc-setting-toggle-listener/18762590#18762590) but it was deleted.

I read the help but I don't understand.

Comment: You posted your comment where an answer is supposed to be posted. You don't have enough privileges yet to comment directly on posts that are not your own (or on answers to your own questions).

Comment: @Oded After a look at the answer I believe that the problem actually was due to a mispelling, and thus the answer would have solved the OP's problem.

Comment: [deleted post](http://imgur.com/g0oV89Z)

Comment: Was does it mean "OP's problem" ?

Comment: @general03 The problem described in the question you answered (specifically, "but it's look like ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGE is not working"). "OP" means original poster and *usually* refers to the asker of a question, though sometimes may be used to refer to the original author of an answer as well.

Answer (score 12):

You didn't post a comment, you posted an *answer*.  That [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18762590/1) didn't actually answer the question though, it was just a comment posted as an answer.  You shouldn't do that; you should only post answers that *answer the question*.  When you have 50 reputation you will be able to post comments.

All of this was explained in the comment posted below your answer:

> Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should not add comments or questions as answer, they will be most likely deleted. You may delete it on your own. If you have a question please ask one but make sure to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient reputation. Deleted post might lead to bad consequences [We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/201151)

If you come across a deleted answer of yours and decide to edit it so that it becomes an appropriate answer, as you have done, you can flag your answer with a custom reason stating that you have fixed the problem and ask for it to be undeleted.  In this case the edit that you made did turn your comment into an answer, you simply failed to notify anyone to undelete it.

Comment: So I have to delete this answer and put it like comment ?

Comment: All is right Duncan has modified the answer

Comment: @Duncan & rene The answer, at the time it was deleted, was `"I have the same issue, do you find a solution ?"`  The author edited it to the given answer **after it was deleted**.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the revision history clearly says the answer got deleted when it said "I have the same issue, do you find a solution ?". It was edited 14 days after that to its current state, the mod didn't make a mistake here.